# Suitable tool for profiling/analysing heap dump jmap file

Tags: java

I have a jmap file already generated .Can anybody suggest a suitable tool to analyse this heap dump file.
Thanks,

Comment: Jvisualvm from your JDK or eclipse MAT: http://www.eclipse.org/mat/
Each have it's shortcomings and advantages

Comment: Hi,I am facing following issues: When i tried to open jmap file in MAT it stated Not supported than i changed the strict rules and file extension to HPROF yet it is giving EOF file exception.Can You advice on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)

Useful links for MAT:
[10 Tips for using the eclipse memory analyzer](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/01/21/10-tips-for-using-the-eclipse-memory-analyzer/)
[How fix memory leaks java](https://dzone.com/articles/how-fix-memory-leaks-java)

Update:

Have you tried, MAT -> File -> Open Heap Dump -> [Right bottom of Screen]  from Combo "All files" -> [Choose files] -> Open

I have tried to dump Eclipse process and read it in MAT without problems.

1. JDK_HOME/bin/jps - this gives you java pid you want to dump

Output:

```
1308 org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
```

2. JDK_HOME/bin/jmap - *jmap -dump:format=b,file=heap.bin 1308*

Output: heap.bin file created in current directory

And than open like described above. It should open without a problems.

Comment: Hi bodo,I used it as it is jmap file throwing parsing exceptions.

Comment: Hi,I am facing following issues: When i tried to open jmap file in MAT it stated Not supported than i changed the strict rules and file extension to HPROF yet it is giving EOF file exception.Can You advice on this?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.Its Working :)